# python merge a new column created from a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge the column generated from a for loop to the main dataframe. The problem is generated column and main df both have different datetime. This should have been simple but I ran into some issues. Main df has datetime data of many days with 1 hr frequency. I have a for loop to generate a new data of 1s frequency. I want to append this data to a new column in the main df. I facing some error.

My code:

```
main_df = 
                       col_A
2019-10-01 09:19:40    10
2019-10-02 09:20:15    20
main_df['new_col'] = ""
for i in main_df.index.date.unique():
   aux_df = day_fun(i) # day_fun generates 1s frequency data under new_col
   # aux_df index is datetime, column is new_col
   main_df['new_col'].loc[i] = pd.concat([main_df, aux_df], axis=1).reindex(main_df.index)
   df['new_col'].loc[i] = aux_df['new_col']

    #for example, aux_df will have following data for 
    # for i='2019-10-01'
    #                      new_col
    #2019-10-01 09:19:40    100
    #2019-10-01 09:21:29    200
    # for i='2019-10-02'
    #                      new_col
    #2019-10-02 09:20:15    300
    #2019-10-02 09:22:39    400
```

Present output:

```
 raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with DataFrame")

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame
```

Expected output:

```
main_df = 
                       col_A   new_col
2019-10-01 09:19:40    10      100
2019-10-02 09:20:15    20      300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mergeasof`.  Just incase, remember to coerce the date to datetime

```
#main_df['date']=pd.to_datetime(main_df['date'])
main_df=main_df.set_index('date').drop(columns=['d','t'])
  print(main_df)

                      col_A
date                      
2019-10-01 09:19:40     10
2019-10-02 09:20:15     20

#aux_df['date']=pd.to_datetime(aux_df['date'])
aux_df=aux_df.set_index('date').drop(columns=['d','t'])
    print(aux_df)

                      new_col
date                        
2019-10-01 09:19:40      100
2019-10-01 09:21:29      200
2019-10-02 09:20:15      300
2019-10-02 09:22:39      400
```

**Solution**

```
# Append one day artifical data to the main_df
for i in main_df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unique():
    aux_df = day_fun(i) # generate artifical data for ith day
    main_df.loc[i] = pd.merge_asof(main_df.loc[i], aux_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)

     

                      col_A  new_col
      date                               
2019-10-01 09:19:40     10      100
2019-10-02 09:20:15     20      300
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The problem is, complete aux_df is not available to execute the solution. For each day in main_df, my code generates a artificial data for aux_df, and now I have to attach this to the main_df.

Comment: It should still work! After `aux_df ` is generated  call the merge ..

Comment: Thanks. I just made a modification to your solution.